# order by clause not working in Cassandra query

Tags: cassandra

I have created a table layer using following code:

```
CREATE TABLE layer (
    layer_name text,
    layer_position text,
    PRIMARY KEY (layer_name, layer_position)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (layer_position DESC)
```

I use the below query to fetch data from the layer table in descending order(layer):

```
$select = new Cassandra\SimpleStatement(<<<EOD
                        select * from layer ORDER BY layer_position DESC
EOD
                      ); 

$result = $session->execute($select);
```

But this query is not working.  Please can anyone help me?

Comment: May be this will help you :- http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/cql-cassandra-query-language/

Comment: thank you but i have tried this also but it can not work.

Comment: when i try to use order by then it gives error like : ORDER BY is only supported when the partition key is restricted by an EQ or an IN. but i doesn't get this issue.

Comment: Please check this 2 similar issues:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274007/select-2000-most-recent-log-entries-in-cassandra-table-using-cql-latest-version                                            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27840329/cassandra-selecting-first-entry-for-each-value-of-an-indexed-column

Comment: i refereed above both links...is it necessary to create a primary key on field which i want to use for order by ?

Comment: I don't know as much but as per their explanation its seems necessary, So I suggest you to try once by that way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99115/discussion-between-nirali-kavar-and-hemdip).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put, Cassandra only enforces sort order *within* a partition key.

```
PRIMARY KEY (layer_name, layer_position)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (layer_position DESC)
```

In this case, `layer_name` is your partition key.  If you specify `layer_name` in your WHERE clause, your results for that value of `layer_name` will be ordered by `layer_position`.

```
SELECT * FROM layer WHERE layer_name = 'layer1';
```

You don't need to specify ORDER BY.  All ORDER BY really can do at the query level is apply a different sort direction (ascending vs. descending).

Cassandra works this way, because it is designed to read data in whatever order it is sorted on disk.  Your partition keys are sorted by hashed token value, which is why results from an unbound WHERE clause appear to be ordered randomly.

**EDIT**

> I have to fetch data using `state_id` column and it should be order by `layer_position`.

Cassandra tables are optimized for a specific query.  While this results in high performance, the drawback is that query flexibility is limited.  The way to solve for this, is to duplicate your data into an additional table designed to serve that particular query.

```
CREATE TABLE layer_by_state_id (
    layer_name text,
    layer_position text,
    state_id text,
    PRIMARY KEY (state_id, layer_position, layer_name)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (layer_position DESC, layer_name ASC);
```

This table will allow queries like this to work:

```
SELECT * FROM layer WHERE state_id='thx1138';
```

And the results will be sorted by `layer_position`, within the requested `state_id`.

Now I am making a couple of assumptions that you will want to investigate:

- I am assuming that `state_id` is a good partitioning key.  Meaning that it has high-enough cardinality to offer good distribution in the cluster, but low-enough cardinality that it returns enough CQL rows to make sorting worthwhile.
- I am assuming that the combination of `state_id` and `layer_position` is *not* enough to uniquely identify each row.  Therefore I am ensuring uniqueness by adding `layer_name` as an additional clustering key.  You may or may not need this, but I'm guessing that you will.
- I am assuming that using `state_id` as a partitioning key will not exhibit unbound growth so as to approach Cassandra's limit of 2 billion cells per partition.  If that is the case, you may need to add an additional partition "bucket."

Comment: hello , i have a one more extra field state_id in this layer table. i have to fetch data using state_id column and it should be order by layer_position. state_id column contains a repeated value.In this case i have tried your code but i doesn't get expected result.

Comment: @Aaron- Thanks a lot...now it is working as per my expectation.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use `order by` directly in Cassandra.

You can apply `order by` on clustering columns only when your partition key will be restricted by `EQ` or `IN`.

Comment: I am sorry but what do you mean by the below line. "You can apply order by on clustering columns only when your partition key will be restricted by EQ or IN."  I am a Cassandra noob.

Comment: @shubhamsharma Thanks. I figured it out after digging through numerous posts. Should have come back to SO and posted my findings. :(

Answer (score -1):

You can use order by clause in cassandra by creating materilaized view table.