# Cassandra's ORDER BY does not work as expected

Tags: database, solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

So, I'm storing some statistics in cassandra.
I want to get the top 10 best entrys based on a specific column. The column in this case is `kills`.

As there is no `ORDER BY` command like in mysql, I have to create a `PARTITION KEY`.

I've created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stats ( uuid uuid, kills int, deaths int, playedGames int, wins int, srt int, PRIMARY KEY (srt, kills) ) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (kills DESC);
```

The Problem I have is the following, as you see above, I'm using the column `srt` for ordering because when I'm going to use the column `uuid` for ordering, the result from my select query is totally random and not sorted as expected.

So I tried to add a column with always the same value for my `PARTITION KEY`. Sorting works now, but not really good. When I now try to `SELECT * FROM stats;`, the result is the following:

```
 srt | kills | deaths | playedgames | uuid                                 | wins
-----+-------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------------+------
   0 |    49 |     35 |          48 | 6f284e6f-bd9a-491f-9f52-690ea2375fef |    2
   0 |    48 |     21 |          30 | 4842ad78-50e4-470c-8ee9-71c5a731c935 |    4
   0 |    47 |     48 |          14 | 91f41144-ef5a-4071-8c79-228a7e192f34 |   42
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
   0 |     2 |     32 |          20 | 387448a7-a08e-46d4-81a2-33d8a893fdb6 |   31
   0 |     1 |     16 |          17 | fe4efbcd-34c3-419a-a52e-f9ae8866f2bf |   12
   0 |     0 |     31 |          25 | 82b13d11-7eeb-411c-a521-c2c2f9b8a764 |   10
```

The problem about the result is, that "per kill" amout/value, there is only one row - but there should be definitly more.

So, any idea about using sorting in Cassandra without getting data stripped out?

I also heard about Datastax Enterprise (DSE) which supports solr in querys but DSE is only free for non-productive (and also only for 6 months) and the paid version is, at least what I heared of, pretty expensive (around 4000$ per node). So, is there any alternative like a Datastax Enterprise Community Edtion? Does not make sense but I'm just asking. I haven't found anything from googling so, can I also use solr with the "normal" cassandra?

Thank you for your help!

PS: Please don't mark this as a duplicate of [order by caluse not working in Cassandra query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491215/order-by-caluse-not-working-in-cassandra-query) because it didn't helped me. I already googled like 1 and a half hour for a solution.

**EDIT**:

Because of the fact that my primary key is `PRIMARY KEY(srt, kills)`, the combination of `(srt, kills)` must be unique. Which basicly means, that rows with the same amout of `kills` are getting overwritten by each other. I would use `PRIMARY KEY(uuid, kills)` which would solve the problem with overwriting rows but when I do `SELECT * FROM stats LIMIT 10` then, the results are totally random and not sorted by `kills`.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to use column for sorting get it out from partition key. Rows will be sorted by this column within every partition - Cassandra splits data between nodes using partition key, and ordering it in each partition using clustering key:

   PRIMARY KEY ((srt), kills)

EDIT:
You need to understand concepts a little bit more, i suggest you to take some free course on DSE site, it can help you with further development.

Anyway, about your question:
Primary key is a set of columns that make each row unique.
There are 2 types of columns in this primary key - partition key columns and clustering columns.
You can't use partition key for sorting or range queries - it is against the model of Cassandra - such query will be splitted to several nodes, or even all nodes and sstables. If you want to use both of the listed columns for sorting, you can use other column for partitioning (random number from 1 to 100 for example), and then you need to execute your query for each "batch", or simply use another column that has high enough number of unique values (at least 100),the data is evenly distributed between such values, and data is accessed using all these values, otherwise you will end up with hot nodes/partitions.

Primary key ((another_column), kills, srt)

What you have to understand, you can order your data only within partitions, but not between partitions.

2. that "per kill" amout/value - can you elaborate? There are only one row for each key in Cassandra, if you insert several rows with same key they will be overwritten with last insert values (read about upserts).

Comment: Well, I'm a bit dumb. Because `kills` is a `PRIMARY KEY` it is correct that there are only around 50 rows because, as you already wrote, the other are getting overwritten.
So my problem is now, that I want to sort on a specific column which can't be a `PRIMARY KEY` but it must be a `PRIMARY KEY` because otherwise I could not sort on that column. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited my question, hope you understand now, what my problem is - sorry for being unclear.